# Last Word From String - Explode()?

Tags: php, arrays, string

So I'm trying to get the last word from a string...

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $row["post_content"]);
print_r($pieces);
$customerEmail = array_pop($pieces);
echo "Email: " . $customerEmail."<br><br>";
```

`$row["post_content"]` = `I wish I could be the icing on the cake..whipped snapbac50@gmail`

Running the code gets me:

```
Array ( [0] => I [1] => wish [2] => I [3] => could [4] => be [5] => the [6] => icing [7] => on [8] => the [9] => cake..whipped snapbac50@gmail.com ) Email: cake..whipped snapbac50@gmail.com
```

I want the end of the array to echo just the email. Why does it include `cake...whipped` before the email if I `array_pop()`? I just want the email.

Comment: works for me: http://ideone.com/rlxGeB perhaps its not a regular space?

Comment: You can run something like this https://eval.in/779902 to see what your characters actually are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the string contains whitespace characters other than spaces, you will have to use a different function: `preg_split('/\s+/', $row['post_content']);`

This will split the string using the pcre regular expression for one or more whitespace characters.